# Why is OpenGL fixed-function pipeline seeming to occasionally only partially render individual draw calls?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I realize that the OpenGL fixed-function pipeline is thoroughly deprecated by this point, but the engine I'm working with is built upon an old codebase that had never demonstrated any problem of this sort until I upgraded my development machine this month and I'd *really* rather not rewrite all the rendering architecture when it still fits my needs completely, aside from this bug.

Essentially, while everything in the game I'm developing renders correctly 99.999% of the time, every now and again there will be a single-frame flicker (maybe one frame every 20 seconds or so?). I recorded video to catch a frame-by-frame comparison of what was flickering and discovered that on these sporadic frames, only *part* of what ought to be an indivisible sprite on my end is being rendered.

An example of what I mean
[image: An example of what I mean]
(correct output on the left, glitchy frame on the right)

[And a larger example (note the errors on the left side of the screen)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJ28B.jpg)

The engine outputs these draw calls in a fixed order each frame, and yet sometimes some of them appear to be skipped such that things which are drawn later appear, while things which should always be drawn *before* them do not.

If one looks closely, you can see that all the text-rendering glitches involve skipping blocks of exactly 8 glyphs, but when I peered into the text-rendering code, each complete label is sent between a single pair of `glBegin(GL_QUADS)` and `glEnd()`, which to the best of my understanding should be an indivisible action. How can OpenGL render *some* of those vertices but not others?

Here's the actual code specifically for that label rendering:

```
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    for (int i = startChar * 8; i < endChar * 8; i+=2)
    {
        glTexCoord2f(texCoord[i], texCoord[i+1]);
        glVertex3f(x + vertCoord[i], y + vertCoord[i+1], z);
    }
    glEnd();
```

And yet, 1 frame in 2000 or something will seemingly ignore groups of exactly 32 of these vertices.

I've been stymied trying to figure out *any* possible cause to this problem, as it's well out of my depth and appears to be essentially 'impossible', as best goes my limited understanding of OpenGL operation (and I want to stress that this code has been unchanged for ages and only began to demonstrate problems when run on my new PC). I'm wondering if anyone could potentially at least point me in the direction of something that *could* cause this sort of issue....

Edit: Since it was asked, I'm running Windows 10 with an GeForce GTX 1060. Previous system where this bug did *not* occur was Windows 7 with a Radeon HD 4850, in case this might be relevant.

Comment: I'd say there is not just text missing. So why do you think the text rendering is the problem? I also highly doubt that one can diagnose the problem just from your description. Please try to provide a complete and verifiable example and an description of your hardware, os, etc.

Comment: Well, I mentioned the text thing specifically because, of the affected render calls, it has the simplest code to quote. I don't think it's 'at fault' so much as the simplest example of a more general fault (and the 'always skip exactly 8 glyphs' bit might be a useful hint for someone who understands OpenGL better than I do?)

And forgive my ignorance, but what do you mean by a 'complete and verifiable example'? Those screenshots _are_ an example of what the glitch looks like.

Comment: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)   And, is the GTX driver updated?

Comment: The drivers are up to date. Also, that link does not appear to work for me, I'm afraid.

Comment: @DracoOmega that is the problem new AMD drivers are buggy and "flickers" a lot in games , in aps, in OpenGL 1.0 code in  newer GL stuff sometimes too. You should revert to some older version that works. The usual symptoms are: changing color for parts of scene (even if the whole scene is rendered with the same code and color). Flickering background. Wrong flickering pixels in shaders.

Answer (score 0):

Well after spending some time on test machine with AMD Radeon R7 to debug similar issue on one of my apps this helped me:

my app was combining transparent and solid objects (just few) using old **GL 1.0** api due to compatibility reasons (as with VBO and other stuff there is always some problem in one card or another so the user can always switch to **GL 1.0**).

We usually use **nVidia** cards for control **PC** but this time we had to use **AMD** and after Installing drivers strange flickering occurs. Part of scene was changing color randomly on each frame render. All the objects where rendered with the same code (even function) and some where OK all the time and some where flickering all the time.

Removing transparency got no effect so that was not the point. AMD where picky about the number and type of vertexes rendered in the past and it seems the behavior returns (after some constant number of faces rendered). I also remembered on similar problem with **Intel** which was really picky about color description.

So I combined both errors and find the place where my App start to do strange thing and place there

```
glColor4f(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
```

To reset the Alpha channel (which was not used in that part of code at all just in the transparency and reseted correctly there). And it solved my issues (at least for now).

Without **MCVE** I can only guess if your issue is related to this but you might try to add some dummy `glColor4f` calls through out your rendering code to see if the behavior changes ...

To help emphasize your problem try to increase the number of rendered faces per frame (without clear screen or buffer swap) as it tends to be tighted to number of rendered faces (processed vertexes).